# How to implement factory pattern with dagger using annotation

Tags: java, design-patterns, module, factory, dagger

What I have done currently is

Created an abstract class

```
public interface AbstractRawPathStrategy {
    String getRouteKey();

    void processRequest();
}
```

Implemented the classes

```
public class GetDocumentImpl implements AbstractRawPathStrategy {
    @Override
    public String getRouteKey() {
        return "GET_DOCUMENT";
    }

    @Override
    public void processRequest() {
        log.info("Inside get document");
    }
}
```

Created a routing factory

```
public class RawPathStrategyFactory {
    private final Map<String, AbstractRawPathStrategy> dictionary;

    @Inject
    public RawPathStrategyFactory(final Set<AbstractRawPathStrategy> abstractRawPathStrategySet) {
        dictionary = new HashMap<>();
        for (AbstractRawPathStrategy abstractRawPathStrategy : abstractRawPathStrategySet) {
            dictionary.put(abstractRawPathStrategy.getRouteKey(), abstractRawPathStrategy);
        }
    }

   
    public AbstractRawPathStrategy getByRouteKey(final String rawPath) {
        return dictionary.get(rawPath);
    }
}
```

Instantiated the factory

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public RawPathStrategyFactory getRouteKeyStrategyFactory() {
        Set<AbstractRawPathStrategy> abstractRouteKeyStrategies = new HashSet<>();
        abstractRouteKeyStrategies.add(new GetDocumentImpl());
        abstractRouteKeyStrategies.add(new GetUserRightsImpl());
        return new RawPathStrategyFactory(abstractRouteKeyStrategies);
    }
```

What I want is to go to respective class based on the route key (String). How can this be done without instantiating each class with new in AppModule. Any cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use multibindings when create RawPathStrategyFactory
https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/multibindings.html

Answer (score 0):

The easy, boring, way would be to use some static identifier which you'll have to set for each distinct subtype of your abstract class, and subsequent subtype thereof.

The more complicated, albeit fun, way to do this would be to use reflection.

Comment: do you have any references for both?